# Julia - generate an array of functions programmatically

Tags: julia

I want to generate an array of functions programmatically, with a loop so that each successive function depends on the previous.

For example in pseudo-code:

```
f_array = [f1, f2, f3]
with:
f1(x) = x
f2(x) = 3 * f1(x)
f3(x) = 3 * f2(x)

so that I could call:
f_array[3](x)
and get the result of f3(x)
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  # create simple function just to initialize
  f(x)=x
  
  # initialize array of functions
  N = 3
  f_array = fill(f, N)
  
  # now we update each function
  for i in 2:N
    f_array[i] = (f(x)= 3 * f_array[i-1](x))
  end
```

I get an error:

> ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type getfield(Main,
> Symbol("#f#15")){Int64} to an object of type typeof(f)

I cannot find a solution at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `fill` with `f` it sets expected type for the elements of `f_array` to `f`, in the code below I am switching to abstract type to make it possible to have any function in the array

```
  # create simple function just to initialize
  f(x)=x
  
  # initialize array of functions
  N = 3
  f_array = Array{Function}(undef, N);
  f_array[1] = f;

  # now we update each function
  for i in 2:N
    f_array[i] = x -> 3 * f_array[i-1](x)
  end

  print(f_array[3](2))
```

which produces a value of 18

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, I also found a way using metaprogramming. I post this here as it could be useful for others:

```
f1(x) = x

for i in 2:N
  prog = "f$i(x) = 3 * f$(i-1)(x)"
  exp = Meta.parse(prog)
  eval(exp)
end

f3(2)
# 18
```

Comment: Don't use a string and parse use `:(f$i(x)...` quote.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write Yegor's answer as

```
f_array = Function[identity]
for i in 2:3
     push!(f_array, x -> 3f_array[i-1](x))
end
```

But more importantly, this is a well known pattern: iterated function application.  And it is already implemented, not in Base, but for example in [IterTools.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/IterTools.jl/stable/#IterTools.iterated), by which you should be able to write:

```
f_array(start, N) = collect(Iterators.take(iterated(x -> 3x, start), N))
```

(I didn't test this, though.)